# How can I choose the option in the selectbox according to the data that comes with the get method?

Tags: javascript

```
function getUrlVars(){
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value){
      vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}

var getBt = getUrlVars()["bt"];
```

**According to the getBt variable here, how can I do 'checked' from the options below to the value equal to value?**

So, for example, if the value of getBt is 2, I want to select the radio option with value 2.

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Filter[type][]" checked="" value="0" class="custom-control-input">
        <div class="custom-control-label">All</div>
    </label>
    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Filter[type][]" value="1" class="custom-control-input">
        <div class="custom-control-label">option1</div>
    </label>
    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Filter[type][]" value="2" class="custom-control-input">
        <div class="custom-control-label">option2</div>
    </label>
    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Filter[type][]" value="3" class="custom-control-input">
        <div class="custom-control-label">option3</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't quite understand the question. Do you want to get selected value from radio button using Javascript?

Comment: @bishwa.poudel No, I want to select the radio option that contains the data received by get method from the form on another page.

Comment: ohh.. okay, so, first you are parsing the URL to get query params, and check the radiobutton in form according to the value you got in URL?

Comment: @bishwa.poudel yes, but how is it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your method of parsing URL is working fine, and variable `getBt` contains the value that you wanted to be checked in radio button, there are couple of solution that you might try.

### 1. Using Vanilla JS

We can use attribute selector in DOM by using `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` methods.

```
let getBt = 2; // value populated by parsing URL
let radioButton = document.querySelector(`[name="Filter[type][]"][value='${getBt}']`);;
radioButton.checked = true;
```

### 2. Using jQuery

JQuery makes DOM manipulation easier, and for including that in your project, include the following in your project html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now in JS file, just write this:

```
$(`input[value=${getBt}]`).attr("checked", "checked")
```

*PS: You can choose any solution to solve the issue. Hope it works.*

You can find both version of solution in this [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-wngncu?file=script.js)

Comment: yes, it works, but it should only be valid for input[name="Filter[type][]"] in order not to interfere with other inputs.

Comment: @AhmetÇetintaş I have updated answer accordingly. Take a look at it.